What is this connector called and are they commonly used?
I'll probably end up just cutting it off but I'm kind of curious now.
I found it on a 12vdc water pump.


Related: Component identification question guidelines

That is called an SAE connector. See this page, SAE Connector section down the page.
Motorola uses them on their two-way radios, so they're rather common.

Maybe this for an example: https://www.ebay.com/itm/305347686144

Awesome thanks so much

They're fairly commonly used for aftermarket 12V equipment in general.  Their design makes it difficult to short the 12V and 0V connections.  If 12V from the battery is provided in the enclosed side, then it's also difficult to short against body metalwork.  The OP's picture is probably the "equipment" side connector with 12V exposed, intended to plug into an equivalent connector from the battery with 12V enclosed.

Those are SAE J928 connectors. @Jeff O. explains that, no, they aren't.
A rare example of a connector that is both self-mating and hermaphrodite.
Note: they are not just "SAE" connectors because a range of different connectors are also "SAE" connectors. Therefore, do specify that they are "J928" SAE connectors.

What do you mean by "self-mating" here? I'm not really familiar with the term, but it seems like it usually means "can mate with other identical connectors," so it's not quite obvious to me how a connector could be self-mating but not hermaphroditic, or hermaphroditic but not self-mating.

Self-mating = mates to itself. hermaphroditic = has both pins and sockets. "self-mating but not hermaphroditic" example: Anderson Power SB connectors. They mate to themselves so they are self-mating. They have neither pins (male) nor sockets (female), so they are not hermaphrodite.

"SAE connector" is commonly used as the unofficial name, but this is a misnomer. Ironically, SAE does not have a defined standard for this 2-pin style connector. It is not regulated by SAE, but it was unofficially created as a modified version of a 4-pin connector that is defined by the SAE J1239 standard.
SAE International (formally SAE, Society of Automotive Engineers) is a professional association who defines official standards for products that are recognized internationally by various industries and government entities. SAE has defined standards for various types of connectors, such as SAE J1962 (OBD-II diagnostic port on US vehicles) and SAE J1772 (common car charger port in North America). Referring to any of these simply as "SAE connectors" would be incomplete and insufficient to identify them from one-another.
There is no official name for this 2-pin connector, no official standard for this connector, and there are no official specifications, such as voltage rating, or maximum electrical current rating. Unofficially, it is a two-conductor version of the four-conductor overmold connector defined by SAE J1239. This standard only covers 4-pin, 5-pin, and 8-pin connectors, which are specifically used for trailer wiring.
It is also incorrect to refer to this 2-pin connector as an "SAE J928" connector, which is what one other response stated. The SAE J928 standard only covers the individual electrical contact pin and receptacle (bullet and barrel style terminals). It is not a standard for the overmold connector assembly which contains these contact pins. SAE J1239 leverages SAE J928 as one of the requirements for the connector assembly.

SAE J928 (electrical contacts) was originally issued in 1965.
SAE J1239 (4-pin trailer connector) was originally issued in 1978.
These unofficial 2-pin connectors were developed in the 1980’s and widely commercialized without any official standard.

Note that SAE J1239 limits the maximum electrical current to 7.5 amps per circuit (for trailer wiring), but people are running these 2-pin connectors at higher current because there is technically no official standard that they follow. You can find these with 10AWG wire, but the electrical contact pins used in the connector cannot match the capacity of 10AWG wire. The contact pins will depend on the manufacturer, but bullet and barrel style crimp terminals are often capable of 15 Amps (same as 14-gauge wire), or even more.
The SAE standards must be purchased from sae.org in order to access them. However, a print was posted here:
https://img.antpedia.com/standard/pdf/L23/1705/SAE%20J%20928-2006.pdf
Another write-up on this topic is available here:
https://web.archive.org/web/20190701114324/http://sae2pin.com/tag/j928/

Jeff O. - Hi, you seem to be disagreeing with an answer, as if your post follows theirs, forum-style. That doesn't work on SE as yours might appear above or below any other, depending on the display order. Instead, always write an answer (which is what this is) to answer the original question. It should be written as if it's the only answer. The original question doesn't claim anything, so starting the answer with "incorrect" doesn't make sense. || If you just had a concern about an answer, then when you had 50 points you could post a comment there. But a full answer like this, is also ok.

Sam G - thank you for letting me know. I'm new hew and thought I was responding to Davide Andrea's post. I lack the 50 points, so I have re-written my response to provide a thorough answer to the original posted question.

"It is also incorrect to refer to this 2-pin connector as an "SAE J928" connector". Thank you, thank you for your correction. I will make that correction in my book.
